# Scheme Guile: remove only first occurrence from a list (non destructive)

Tags: list, scheme, guile

I would need to remove the first occurrence of an element from a list in a non destructive way.

According to the [Guile Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/List-Modification.html) there are a set of functions to do it in a destructive way (delq1!, delv1!, delete1!). On the other hand the non destructive versions remove all the occurrences of the element.

I know I could write a function (may be by means of filter) to do it in a couple of lines but I was wondering if there exist a better/standard method to do it.

As a matter of example, giving the list

```
((1 2) (3 4) (1 2))
```

when removing the element

```
(1 2)
```

I expect the result be

```
((3 4) (1 2))
```

whereas the original list remains

```
((1 2) (3 4) (1 2)).
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scheme, the standard solution is to create a new list, but without the element. In the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI_002d1-Deleting.html#index-list-delete), we see that the `delete` procedure eliminates all occurrences of the element - so we have to roll our own solution, but it's simple:

```
(define (delete-1st x lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((equal? (car lst) x) (cdr lst))
        (else (cons (car lst)
                    (delete-1st x (cdr lst))))))
```

For example:

```
(delete-1st '(1 2) '((1 2) (3 4) (1 2)))
=> '((3 4) (1 2))
```

Comment: Your solution is missing a `cons` somewhere. Anyway, the OP was wondering if there were a built-in way to achieve it, which there isn't. :-(

Comment: Great! it works! Thanks a lot! I only would like to point for the sake of completing the post that on the example it should be (delete-1st '(1 2) '((1 2) (3 4) (1 2)))

Answer (score 1):

Here are five versions of `delete1` and one version of `delete1!`. Each removes from the returned list the first element found to be equal to the given element. The latter ones are more optimal for time and space. Destructive functions are not used, except in the last part where their proper use is considered.

The first is the non-tail recursive:

```
(define (delete1a v l) 
  (let loop ((l l))
    (if (null? l) '()
        (if (equal? v (car l)) 
            (cdr l)
            (cons (car l) (loop (cdr l)))))))
```

Then the second and third are tail recursive but inefficient has they copy more than needed. For example if the item is not found the entire list is copied.

```
 (define (delete1b v l)
   (let loop ((l l) (a '()))
     (if (null? l) (reverse a)
         (if (equal? v (car l)) 
             (append (reverse a) (cdr l))
             (loop (cdr l) (cons (car l) a))))))
```

The third contains a fusion of `(append (reverse l) m)` and removes the useless `(reverse a)` when the end of the list is reached but it still accumulates a copy of the list in `a` that would be needed for that `(reverse a)`:

```
 (define (append-reverse l m) 
   (if (null? l)
       m
       (append-reverse (cdr l) (cons (car l) m))))

 (define (delete1c v ls)
   (let loop ((l ls) (a '()))
     (if (null? l) ls
         (if (equal? v (car l)) 
             (append-reverse a (cdr l))
             (loop (cdr l) (cons (car l) a))))))
```

In the fourth version the accumulator is replaced with a counter:

```
(define (delete1d v ls)
   (let loop ((l ls) (a 0))
     (if (null? l) ls
         (if (equal? v (car l)) 
             (append (take ls a) (cdr l))
             (loop (cdr l) (+ a 1))))))
```

When `take` is implemented tail recursively it must reverse its result but we already have an `append-reverse` so why not a `take-reverse` that returns its result in reverse order so `(append (take a b) c)` is replaced by `(append (reverse (take-reverse a b)) c)` and then by `(append-reverse (take-reverse a b) c)`:

```
(define (append-reverse l m) 
  (if (null? l)
      m
      (append-reverse (cdr l) (cons (car l) m))))

(define (take-reverse l n)
  (let loop ((l l) (n n) (a '()))
    (if (= n 0) a
        (if (null? l) a
            (loop (cdr l) (- n 1) (cons (car l) a))))))

(define (delete1e v ls)
  (let loop ((l ls) (a 0))
    (if (null? l) ls
        (if (equal? v (car l)) 
            (append-reverse (take-reverse ls a) (cdr l))
            (loop (cdr l) (+ a 1))))))
```

The result of doing so is that the list is walked once and no copying is done if the value is not found and if the value is found only the prefix of the list before the element is walked and copied two more times. Once in `take-reverse` and then once in `append-reverse`.

If destructive functions were allowed the copying of the list prefix could be safely reduced to once using `append-reverse!` rather than `append-reverse` as in `(append-reverse (take-reverse ls a) (cdr l))` the result of `(take-reverse ls a)` is a copy that is linearly used by `(append-reverse r (cdr l))`. There are type systems that can prove that such is safe:

```
(define (append-reverse! l m) 
  (if (null? l)
      m
      (let ((next (cdr l)))
        (begin (set-cdr! l m)
               (append-reverse next l)))))
```

But one might go even further and define `delete1!`:

```
(define (delete1! v l)
  (let loop ((left '()) (right l))
    (if (null? right) l
        (if (equal? (car right) v) 
            (if (null? left) (cdr right)
                (begin (set-cdr! left (cdr right)) 
                       l))
            (loop right (cdr right))))))
```

This walks the list once and does no copying.